# Live timesheet editing and saving

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, excel, yii

Greeting everyone, here I go.

I'm currently trying to think of how it would be best to make editable spreadsheet like this one:

Here's [Work on Project timesheet](http://goo.gl/iLx2jz)!.

(example is Excel spreadsheet, I need one made in html format),
which is generated via pre-set data, on forms. So the main criteria is that all those numbers and letters in range H24:AL103 (see the example attachement) must be editable live and saved on temporary table (PHP, AJAX, MYSQL). Principle like in Google docs. I enter something, quit it and can return whenever I want and continue editing it with its saved progress. It has to be in almost same format as example and all fields must be active for editing or changes. Data inverse to H24:AL103 is calculated or pre-set from database tables. In the end user can press completed and table is no longer editable and waiting for verification after which it is exportable to .xls, .pdf and printable.

Anyone can offer any practices on this one? P.S. Best ones would be specifically for Yii framework.

As well can you help me on making database structure for this example? So everything would be put into one table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery for this, giving each box a unique ID, and on click, opens a pop up box which contains the text/values, and on clicking off the box, any changes are done via POST to a .php script which updates the value on the server, AJAX.

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need something which requires no popups, just plain update on typing input.

Comment: My linked example is what you want then, my comment about the pop up was just something you COULD do